# how to get textbox array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form below.

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name"><br>
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

and this is my function uploadFile.

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var name = _("name").value;
    alert(name); 
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    formdata.append("name", name);
```

Now my problem is I want to get the value of my textbox array which is the `name[]`..when I try to alert the name variable only the first index is showing up..any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance..

Comment: does .value need parenthesis?

Comment: nope @Csteele5 ,i just need the value of name[].

Comment: Why are you getting the `input type=text` as an array? you can simply get it from the `.value` prop....

Comment: Avoid using duplicate id's, BTW what is `_()`?

Comment: Hi @Arvind _() is 
`function _(e){ return document.getElementById(e); }`

Answer (score 2):

> `getElementsByName` will return all the elements([**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) having name provided in `argument`

```js
function uploadFile() {
  var names = document.getElementsByName('name[]');
  for (var i = 0, iLen = names.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    alert(names[i].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

Comment: @JordanDavis, What would you suggest then ? Considering performance ?

Comment: first not using `getElementsByName`... you should pass `this` in the `uploadFile(this)` and then call `element.parent.children` and then loop through the children like you have above,  and secondly he shouldn't be using a text `array` instead of using a string....

Comment: `element.parent.children`  will come into picture if OP has more than one forms in his page. `name[]` becomes helpful to manipulate at server end, What if OP wants to validate fields at client side and then submit the form ?

Comment: it doesn't help at all serverside... and it's way slower and pointless... what would be the point to declare it an array vs. string? If it's multiple files then the only array should be the `name=file[]` so that when you upload multiple files they are stored as an array....

Comment: If you have any input field with name as [] then it will be treated as array while processing it at server side..I am looking forward to hear some demonstration about why it is slower and pointless..

Comment: Why wouldn't you want it as an array on the server... thats what you want so it's easy to loop through... again what would be the point for declaring a char array.

Answer (score 1):

The getElementsByName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as a NodeList object.

```
var mynames= document.getElementsByName("name[]");
console.log(mynames[0].value); //Outputs "atrib name 1"
```

Comment: Hi @Suresh, I tried your suggestion but I got this error.. `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest asynchronous multiple file uploader... this is the most compute and memory efficient.... for clarity reason I left the css out.

"[You Can Thank Me Later](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDNaVtTzPvg)" - *Drake "jimmy brooks" Graham*

//HTML & JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
function uploadFile(formdata){  
    var data = new FormData();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    for(var i=0; i < formdata.length; i++){
        if(formdata[i].tagName !== "BUTTON"){                 
            if(formdata[i].type === "file"){                
                for(var x=0; x < formdata[i].files.length; x++){
                    data.append(formdata[i].files[x].name, formdata[i].files[x]);
                }
            }
            else{
                data.append(formdata[i].name, formdata[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    request.open("POST", "dump.php");
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4){
            console.log(request.response);
        }
    }   
}
</script>   
</head>
    <body>  
        <form onsubmit="return false;">
          <input type="text" name="name">
          <input type="file" multiple>
          <button onclick="uploadFile(this.parentNode.children)">Upload Files</button>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

//PHP (dump response back to callback)

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);   
    var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to alert the name variable only the first index is showing
>   up

As per your comment:

```
function _(e){ return document.getElementById(e); }
```

Problem is `getElementById()` returns you the first html element with the given id no matter how many other elements exists on the page with same id.

First thing avoid duplicate `id` on a page, as suggested by other possibly you can go for accessing the text-box with name attribute:

```js
var names = document.getElementsByName("name[]");
var values = [];
var i = names.length;
while (i--)
  values.unshift(names[i].value);
alert(values);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="Alex" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="James" />
```